# changing the pass phrase on a key from openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl

A while ago I created a key with `openssl genrsa -aes256 4096 > server.key`.  The process prompts for a pass phrase.  I would now like to change that pass phrase, is that possible?

Comment: I am certain it is possible, not sure about the syntax off the top of my head.  I spend a fair amount of time reading the man page last time I needed to do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use AES, e.g. AES256 [instead of Triple DES](https://superuser.com/a/550316/224116):

```
openssl rsa -aes256 -in server.key -out newserver.key
```

Comment: We need the original passphrase for this to work.  If that is lost, is there a way to reset this?

Comment: @Jordan generate a new key/cert pair and distribute them. If there was a way to "reset" the key passphrase, there's nothing to prevent someone else from doing so and stealing the plaintext key.

Answer (score 8):

If you have `ssh-keygen` installed, this is simpler :

`ssh-keygen -p -f server.key`

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people ask. Part of writing a good answer is providing context for the proposed solution. Please edit your answer and explain why your solution works, and what, *specifically*, it does.

Comment: I do not see the point of the previous comment. I have just checked that this answer is useful and actually let change the password of an openssl key in-place without the need to save into a new file.

Comment: I find this solution better that the others, as you don't have to remember or introspect the key file to figure out the encryption algorithm: `ssh-keygen` will do that for you.

Comment: It should be noted this this command by default will convert the key to OpenSSH private key format, which may or may not be what you want depending on what you are going to use the key for. The -m parameter can be used to override.

Comment: A possible positive difference with this way is that it allows me to specify *no* passphrase for the new key; the `openssl` way does not, it insists on at least 4 character passphrase LOL.

Answer (score 6):

```
openssl rsa -des3 -in server.key -out newserver.key
```

Comment: The syntax is correct, but there really isn't a good reason to keep using Triple DES. It becomes *extremely* vulnerable with certain passphrase lengths.

Comment: @Dennis - How well supported are the alternative cyphers, and how how big a problem is it really  (ie if someone can get physically get the private key surely you have bigger problems).   You are probably technically right in what you say, but I've never seen an SSL cert provider suggest anything else, and wonder why)

Comment: Triple DES was an emergency drop-in replacement for DES when the first brute-force attack was successful. In November 2001, it was superseded by AES (*Advanced* Encryption Standard); AES is faster, provides more security for keys of the same length and supports longer keys. Support for AES should be at least as good as support for Triple DES by now.

Comment: so is `openssl rsa -aes -in server.key -out newserver.key` the recommended method for changing pass phrases then?

Comment: looks like it would be `openssl rsa -aes256 -in server.key -out newserver.key`. You can also use `-aes192` or `-aes128`.

Comment: @WildVelociraptor - Post your own answer instead of editing 2 year old answers.